# SQL Server equivalent to MySQL enum data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, types

Does SQL Server 2008 have a a data-type like MySQL's `enum`?

Comment: Found this interesting approach when I wanted to implement enums in SQL Server. The approach mentioned below in the link is quite compelling, considering all your database enum needs could be satisfied with 2 central tables. [SQL SERVER – Enumerations in Relational Database – Best Practice](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/22/sql-server-enumerations-in-relational-database-best-practice/)

Comment: @user_v This is a variation of the anti-pattern known as "one true (lookup) table". The proper approach is to have separate table for each enum type and use foreign keys (if you need lookup at all, which may not be the case for "pure" enums).

Comment: @user_v The comments on the linked page provide good backup for using individual tables for each "enum", rather than what this answer specifies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419847/what-is-a-lookup-table Seems to be the solution for this, as suggested by some answers here.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

It doesn't.  There's a vague equivalent:

```
mycol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (mycol IN('Useful', 'Useless', 'Unknown'))
```

Comment: Why not use a table that defines valid values, and then use a foreign key constraint instead?

Comment: @Elaskanator I'd say this most precisely answers the direct OP, while the best solution for it is probably the FK+external table usage.

Comment: Thank you @Elaskanator for reminding me of the obvious... normalize the data and enum's stop existing.

Comment: @Elaskanator Often enum values are defined in application code first (e.g. C# `enum`), whereas if they used a table FK reference then those supposedly static enum entries could be modified at runtime which would be undesirable (and SQL Server doesn't support the concept of immutable tables), finally if you have lots of enums with only a few values then you'll end-up adding lots of tables to your database. Not to mention extra IO reads due to FK constraint-checking when inserting/deleting data, whereas a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` is much faster and doesn't cause database object spam.

Comment: I agree with @dai. I used to use code-tables, but I see them as overkill. I like the CHECK functionality, and varchar. It allows you to use a static Enum in C# without a bunch of fancy workarounds. Performance-wise, sqlserver is perfectly capable of indexing strings almost as well as ints or smallints. The performance gain is minimal compared to the additional coding complexity. Time is money.

Comment: @JamesO'Brien That is a naïve assumption to make without understanding the particular use case. It probably wont make the world of difference with a small table but all other things being equal int's consume a lot less space. This helps to keep your index size leaner and reduce page IO's. On a very big table this can make a drastic difference. Sorting is also a lot more expensive in terms of CPU resources, and collation can have an impact. If working with large amounts of data it is important to benchmark before making these kinds of assumptions.

Comment: @JamiePearcey Well yes - it depends on your particular use case. I more meant that this is another option. I ended up going back to code tables for enums on my current project.

Comment: @Elaskanator - why do I want to incur the overhead of locking that table every time I want to use something that is, for all intents-and-purposes, a constant?  How difficult would it be to implement an Enum in the language?

Comment: @Quarkly "How difficult would it be to implement an Enum in the language?" is not a reasonable question.

Comment: @Elaskanator - Only unreasonable people think in those terms.  For those who can reason, it's a static list of constants.  No table locking, no additional indices to navigate and the free version of SQL already has it.

Comment: @Elaskanator That would work for a single-choice `ENUM` but not for a multiple-choice `SET`.

Comment: Using text values with limitation by CHECK has several disadvantages: uses more memory, has no user-defined order, is defined by column (has to be defined redundantly in several places unless defined as a domain).

Answer (score 107):

The best solution I've found in this is to create a lookup table with the possible values as a primary key, and create a foreign key to the lookup table.

Comment: A better solution from a maintainability perspective than the check constraint shown above.

Comment: This is a better solution than Enums - in MySQL as well.

Comment: @ypercube Why is it better for MySQL as well?

Comment: @BenRecord There are several issues with MySQL's enums: [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/). I don't agree 100% that it's evil but you have to be extra careful when using them.

Comment: @BenR also if I recall correctly, in non-strict mode with MySQL, an invalid enum can be inserted as a NULL. Whatever the condition, a previous team of mine had issues with a MySQL enum not getting inserted and *not failing* when the value wasn't specified in the list of values.  A foreign key constraint on a lookup table would cause a failure. I agree the lookup table is better for MySQL.

Comment: In addition, the table can be made read-only, if you don't want the lookup table's values to ever be added-to/altered/deleted.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529839/how-to-make-a-table-read-only-in-sql-server

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Same question as above.  Why do I want to incur the cost of locking an extra table every time I want to use a constant?

Comment: @Quarkly what do you mean with "locking an extra table"? There is nothing wrong with **having** one more table in your design. As of why it's better than enums, take for example what would happen if you want to change the data, from 3 possible values to 4. With enums, you have to ALTER the column definition of the table that has the enum or the CHECK constraint (possibly locking the entire - maybe huge - table while doing so). With the extra table and a FK, you only have to insert 1 row. No DDL, no locking.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - No one here is talking about **One** more table in a design.  Including lookup tables for enums multiplies the number of tables locked for a given operation geometrically.  If every table has two 'enum' values as attributes and you have eight tables in a query (before the enum tables are included), then you're looking at 24 table locks instead of eight.  Glad you're small database isn't impacted but the overhead is measurable in my customers' databases.

Comment: @Quackly I know exactly what I said and I did mean one more table (for every enum). Your previous comment has "locking", this one has "locked" and I really cannot fathom why you think that a query that access 24 (or even 240 tables) needs to lock them. I f you mean to do lookup (in those tables), yeah, it might need to.

Comment: Another thing is even though you may have reference/lookup tables instead of enum columns that does not mean that your queries need to use them. I don't have to join my `country` table when I can equivalently do for example `WHERE actual_table_we_need.country_code = 'FR'`

Comment: So with either an enum column or a reference table, your query will have `WHERE actual_table_we_need.country_code = 'FR'`. The only difference is that on the design with reference tables (what is suggested in this answer), you'll have an extra table (for every enum), eg. `country` with a PK of `(country_code)` and an FK from the `actual_table_we_need (country_code) REFERENCES country (country_code)`

Comment: This would work for a single-choice `ENUM` but not for a multiple-choice `SET`.

Comment: A lookup table is nice if the allowed values change regularly. Otherwise, an enum is the way to go as it is far better regarding performance.

Comment: Comparing to "true" enums, both options seem like a lame imitation. Constraints are fast but they do not guarantee that all columns sharing the same data type have the same set of allowed values. Lookup tables do, but they somewhat slow down editing by checking foreign keys. And neither can be used as arguments in functions/procedures.

Answer (score 8):

IMHO Lookup tables is the way to go, with referential integrity. 
But only if you avoid "Evil Magic Numbers" by following an example such as this one:
[Generate enum from a database lookup table using T4](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html)

Have Fun!

Comment: You don't need T4 to do this...

Comment: Haha @MarkSchultheiss you DID notice this was 10 years ago right??

Comment: Yes, just adding a comment for that - not suggesting this was a bad answer or even still is in some places. Sometimes technology changes, imagine that!

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ActionState_Preassigned()
RETURNS tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 0
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION ActionState_Unassigned()
RETURNS tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END

-- etc...
```

Where performance matters, still use the hard values.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution for this is a simple look-up table ([What is a lookup table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571693/7389293)). Nevertheless you can implement something like this:

## Solution

### SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

[image: sql server enum implementation]

`User.Role` is the Foreign Key here, and `Role.Type` is the Primary Key it refers. And in that table, you'll have the following values:

[image: values for enum table]

- The type of which *must match* in both tables. In this case that type is: `nvarchar(15)`
- If you try to add a value at `User.Role` different than those available at the `Role` table, you'll get an error.

[image]

### SQL Code

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](75) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Role] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Role] FOREIGN KEY([Role])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([Type])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Role]
GO
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role](
    [Type] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Role] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Type] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

## Solution 2

You can implement a lookup table like this one: [Create enum in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223873/7389293)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT yourColumn CHECK(yourColumn IN('XL','L','M','S','XS'))
```