# SQL, Temporary make a table read only

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a table Read Only in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529839/how-to-make-a-table-read-only-in-sql-server)

I'm modifing a procedure that makes modifications in a table ( let's call it, base.dbo.important ).

I'm reading the code in order to eliminate all the queries the modify this table.

Is there a way to make that table readonly during the procedure, so that any modification attempt raises an exception ?

I'm using sql-server

Comment: -1 A simple Google search "sql server make a table read only" brought me back to SO. I'm sure it appeared to OP when he/she was composing the question.

Comment: I'm looking for something that works only for that procedure. I saw the previos question

Answer (score 2):

In SQLServer you can deny write-access to the application's user at any level you want (DB, procedure, table column... you name it!)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1138/giving-and-removing-permissions-in-sql-server/

http://tweakingsqlserver.blogspot.com/2009/04/deny-table-permission-at-table-level.html

You can also deny permissions just for the procedure.

http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/705794-deny-user-roles-stored-procedure

Comment: I'm lookin for something that works just for the procedure

Comment: If I understood correctly, OP wants to block one table, not the whole DB

Comment: Yes, You can set permissions on procedures, tables, column etc.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, would be to set the transaction isolation level to serializable and then select from the table from within a transaction. So, something akin to:

```
Set Transaction Isolation Level Serializable;

Begin Tran;

Select *
From MyTable

/* Do more work */

Commit Tran;
```

Comment: https://pastee.org/m3wga; I think this discribes better what I need.

Comment: @Argento - Um. You are deleting from mytemp from within your transaction. I'm assuming you are not trying to make the table read-only to yourself but rather queries external to your transaction.