# Database read only but only few tables writable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to set the database as read only mode with the following command and it works.

```
ALTER DATABASE [TESTDB] SET READ_ONLY WITH NO_WAIT
```

However, I need to allow only few tables like UserSession, etc to be writable.
 Is it possible?

**We have around 500+ tables in the database and we need to allow only 4 tables to be writable.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529839/how-to-make-a-table-read-only-in-sql-server

Comment: @MatSnow we have around 500+ tables in the database and we need to allow only 4 tables to be writable. Should i add 496 read only instead of making whole database as read only and allow only 4 writable?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to set only few tables to be writable if you set the database to read only. I would suggest you to set permissions that fit your needs.

Comment: You can make a separate filegroup and move those writable tables to it. and make the other filegroup as read-only. Refer my answer below.

Comment: Ok its fine to make read only; but what if I need to make *non-read only* (writable) ?

Answer (score 5):

You could deny `INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE` to `public` role like:

```
DENY UPDATE ON tab1 TO public 
DENY INSERT ON tab1 TO public 
DENY DELETE ON tab1 TO public
```

After that, regular users (not sysadmins) will get an error when trying to insert into tab1:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (1)

--Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 20
--The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'tab1', database 'test', schema 'dbo'.
```

If this is something that you're comfortable adding to your database, then you could generate the script to change all tables like:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable '
PRINT ''
    DENY UPDATE ON ? TO public 
    DENY INSERT ON ? TO public 
    DENY DELETE ON ? TO public
''
'
```

Make sure you're not denying writes to those 4 tables that still need to be written to.

Not sure about your application, but if you dont want to deny permissions on `public` role, you may look into creating your own role, denying access on that role, and making users part of that role instead.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Regular users don't usually have these rights. If, however, that's the case, then you can restrict this with either more DENY rights, or you could use a database trigger if the option to change database schema is available (eg: is not 3rd party database that you cannot change)

Comment: Still you cannot deny right to object owner plus you have to rememer to do it for all new users.. Truly read-only is on DB  or filegroup level.'

Comment: I'm not really sure where are you getting at with the rights to object owner - someone will have to create the tables - right? I don't think the question relates to making the db read only in front of empowered users - they always have a way even with filegroup or db in readonly mode.

Comment: As for "you have to remember to do it for all new users", if you are denying rights on public role, you don't need to remember.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to store the two types of tables in different schemas -- say `readable` and `writable`.

When SQL Server introduced schemas in 2005, the [idea](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx) was that schemas are a unit for security and databases are a unit for backup and recovery:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 introduced the concept of database object
>   schemas. Schemas are analogous to separate namespaces or containers
>   used to store database objects. Security permissions apply to schemas,
>   making them an important tool for separating and protecting database
>   objects based on access rights.

This would make two different schemas a strong contender for your data architecture.

In other words, set the `readable` schema to `read_only`.  And put the other tables in the `writable` schema.

Comment: This works in some cases. But the actual data in the database is never made read only. A user with sufficient permissions can still alter the data in 'readable' schema. For example, sysAdmin will be able to directly alter the data.

Comment: @ChamikaGoonetilaka . . . Of course, you can adjust the permissions to be whatever the application needs.  And `'readable" and "writable" may not be the best names.

Comment: @ChamikaGoonetilaka your argument is flawed. The system admin is always capable of enabling the database to be writable. No matter what you do someone with that access is not someone you can stop. THus security is a plan not an absolute.

Answer (score 4):

You can archive this via moving the writable tables to a seperate Filegroup and making the other filegroup readonly.

**Step One - Create a Different Filegroup**

```
ALTER DATABASE TESTDB ADD FILEGROUP Writable_FG;
```

**Step Two - Add a Data File to The New Filegroup**

```
ALTER DATABASE TESTDB ADD FILE (
     NAME = JeanAnn2,
     FILENAME = 'D:\MSSQL\TESTDB_Writable_FG_01.ndf',
     SIZE = 6MB,
     MAXSIZE = 18MB,
     FILEGROWTH = 1
) TO FILEGROUP Writable_FG;
```

**Step Three - Move the tables that you need to be writable, to the new filegroup**

*For this you need to recreate the clustered index of the table on the new filegroup.*

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_YourTable
ON dbo.YourTable(YourClusteringKeyFields)
WITH DROP_EXISTING
ON [Writable_FG]
```

or if your clustered index is *unique*:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_YourTable
ON dbo.YourTable(YourClusteringKeyFields)
WITH DROP_EXISTING
ON [Writable_FG]
```

*Do this for all four tables that you need to be writable.*

**Step Four - Make the other filegroup readonly**

```
ALTER DATABASE TESTDB MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] READ_ONLY;
```

*Here, it is assumed that the other filegroup is the Primary.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [schemaName].[tableName] READ ONLY ON|OFF
```

Comment: I think that's specific to Oracle (11g), while question relates to MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new schema on your database, for example `upd`
Now you can give read & write rights for that schema for particular users that should have ability to modify the data.
After that, you can create updatable/insertable views based on the table that you want to be updated

```
create view upd.Tab1
as 
select * from dbo.Tab1
GO
```

Only objects in schema `upd` will be writable for users with rights to `upd` schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the 4 tables on a differnt database, and on you database 
put a synonym to the database with the 4 tables you wish to update.

```
CREATE SYNONYM sessionTables
SELECT * 
FROM WriteableDatabase.dbo.sessionTables
```