# Is there a way to create custom UserType in ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I'm currently facing a mapping problem which I think would require custom UserTypes.

I have a `PasswordComplexitySpecification` interface with a few concrete implementations such as `SimplePasswordComplexitySpecification` and `ComplexPasswordComplexitySpecification`.

An `Account` holds a `PasswordComplexitySpecification`, which is just an immutable value object, not an entity.

Using a custom UserType, I could just store a discriminator to represent the specification and translate it back to the appropriate specification in the custom UserType. Can this be done in ColdFusion?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434298/sql-server-equivalent-to-mysql-enum-data-type

Comment: @JamesAMohler No, not at all. It's really an ORM problem.