# SQL Server query (create rule)

Tags: sql-server

> Create a rule called `Makedata` to allow only the following values to the make of the data: txt, excel, word, rar, and powerpoint.
>
> You must attach the rule to column `Make` in the datatype table

What does this question mean? I don't want a solution just an explanation.

Thank you

Comment: I think you should be the one who tells us about the question.  Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I am usiing sql server.

Comment: ***Important***

*This feature will be **removed** in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.*

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who asked the question?   This isn't a programming question; it is a reading comprehension question, and is off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: it is not your job : ) your are not obliged to answer : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to filter the values that can be stored in that data column. For this you can use enum data type if were using MySQL. To fit your case take a look at: [SQL Server equivalent to MySQL enum data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434298/sql-server-equivalent-to-mysql-enum-data-type)

Alter your table with:

```
column_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CHECK (column_name IN('txt', 'excel', 'word', 'rar', 'powerpoint'))
```

Comment: I need it as rule

Comment: CREATE RULE your_rule  
AS   
@list IN ('txt', 'excel', 'word', 'rar', 'powerpoint');

Comment: @list  should n't be the same  as column name ?