# Many of many to many?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a big Excel table (please see pic for sample of table). I need to transfer it to a MySQL database.

It seems like I have ended up with a lot of many to many tables. (please see pic of DB Structure of the table)

For whatever reason it just doesn't feel right, are there better ways to build DB Structure of the table?

[image: the table]

[image: my Structure]

Alternative structure:

[image]

[Alternative structure 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kgDU.png)

Comment: I wouldn't have expected quite that many tables. Are the "additional ingredients" different than "main ingredients" and merit their own table? Or why not have just one "ingredients" table? So I would expect a drug table (by name and drug id), an ingredients table (by ingredient name and id), a form table (form type and form id), and perhaps an ingredient type table. Then you'd have a main drug information table that pulls it all together with a date column.

Comment: every column has very special type of pharmaceutical ingredients (its for pharmaceutics ) PLUS will be search by every column(type of ingredients),  its about 10 difference types in a real pharmaceutical table. other words its not possible to mix all difference type of ingredients . very hope i disturbed clearly situation, im new here.

Comment: So there is no overlap in main ingredients and additional ingredients at all? If so, then, sure, make them separate tables. But my other comments still apply. If there's overlap, you could still have them in one table and even have a column indicating whether it's special in some way. But certainly whether an ingredient is additional can be determined by whether it appears in the "additional ingredient" column of a drug. it wouldn't have to be a separate table regardless.

Comment: created Diagram of your suggest (if I got properly ), Please check pic. attached to the post , I've put "form" column into Ingredient table as well.

Comment: That looks  close. Your `ingredients` table has an `ingredients` column, `varchar(5)`. Is that the name of the ingredient? I don't see the `form` column you mentioned.

Comment: i misprinted, "varchar(5)" has to be "varchar (50)" ,, i put "form" column together with "Ingredients" be course now we have "Type Ingredients", i should renamed tables "Type Ingredients" as "Type Columns" and etc.  other words now there is no "form" in the Structure  any more,  only  one more row in "Type Ingredients" aka ("Type Columns") , like this table can have unlimited many to many columns,

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I wondered how you managed to fit an ingredient name in just 5 characters. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure this way:

```
Drugs(id, drug_name, drug_date)
Ingredients(id, ingredient_type_id, ingredient_name, form)
IngredientTypes(id, ingredient_type)
DrugIngredients(id, drug_id, ingredient_id, additional_ingredient_id)
```

DrugIngredients-Drugs is many-to-one, DrugIngredients-Ingredient is many-to-many (on two different columns), and Ingredients-IngredientTypes is many-to-one. In `Ingredients`, the `form` column could be an [enumeration type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434298/sql-server-equivalent-to-mysql-enum-data-type).

Comment: if I got right, i guess you missed a field "Ingredient" in table "Ingredients" BUT i think i got your idea about "DrugIngredients-Ingredient is many-to-many (on two different columns)" : many to many by "ingredient_id" and "additional_ingredient_id", I created diagram your variant , in attached pic.  About "enumeration type." for "form" so it can hold only one value , seems SET can be converted into array in code. but that makes a search on "form" difficult . Please correct me if im not right.